# This not available in complete function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I have this jQuery function

```
$("#edit-modal").animate({ width: "90%" }, 400, function () {
    this.registrationsPanelWidth = $("#edit-modal").width() - this.modalWidth - 20;
    console.log(this.modalWidth);
});
```

however in the `function()` is seems like `this.` isn't known or available, meaning `console.log(this.modalWidth);` results in undefined.

How can I use my `this.property` in my complete function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass in an anonymous function, it gets its own `this` variable.

The quickest way to get around this would be to create a closure reference to `this` in the outer scope, and use the reference variable inside your callback.

```
var self = this;
$("#edit-modal").animate({ width: "90%" }, 400, function () {
    self.registrationsPanelWidth = $("#edit-modal").width() - self.modalWidth - 20;
    console.log(self.modalWidth);
});
```

This is a perfect use case for ES6 arrow functions, by the way. From the documentation on MDN:

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or new.target. These function expressions are best suited for non-method functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.

If you're able to use arrow functions in your project, it would look like this:

```
$("#edit-modal").animate({ width: "90%" }, 400, () => {
    this.registrationsPanelWidth = $("#edit-modal").width() - this.modalWidth - 20;
    console.log(this.modalWidth);
});
```

[See the documentation on MDN for more information on arrow functions.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Then you should use `self` inside callback

Comment: @yurzui is right. Replace your `this` within the JQuery with `self`.

Comment: Sorry, y'all - need more coffee. Example is updated.